# Finding Four Grams in an NLTK Corpus

Tags: python, nltk

I know when you import everything you can do thinks like `nltk.bigrams(nltk.corpus.brown.words()` for bigrams and `nltk.trigrams(nltk.corpus.brown.words()` for triagrams, but how do you do four grams?

I've seen other ways to do it, but they all do it with a "string" or a text they make up. How do you do it with the nltk.corpus.brown? Do you have to covert it to a string and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get n number of items you can use `nltk.ngrams()` with the number to get as the second argument.

In your example, to get four-grams, you can use `nltk.ngrams(nltk.corpus.brown.words(), 4)`

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!